# java thread wait and auto wake up

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an web application which accept some data from user to create a task, then the task should be executed.

Since the execution of the Task is to download something from the internet which will cost some time, so I tried to create a new Thread to do the job.

This is my idea:

1. create a `LoaderThread` used to download data. And the `LoaderThread` hold a field of `ArrayList` used for put the `Task`.
2. A `Servlet` to handle the request and response.
3. When the `Servlet` startup, start the `LoaderThread`
4. During the servlet run, add task to the `LoaderThread`.

This is the code(some of them is omitted):

```
public class RwdServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private StaticMapLoader loader;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();

        loader = new StaticMapLoader();
        loader.startRunning();
    }
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Task t=createTask(req);
        loader.addTask(t);
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        loader.stopRunning();
    }
}


public class StaticMapLoader extends Thread {
    private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
    private boolean running = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            if (tasks.size() > 0) {
                Task t = tasks.get(0);
                log.info(t);
                if (t != null && t.status == Status.waiting) {
                    tasks.remove(0);
                    t.status = Status.running;
                    downLoad(t);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void downLoad(Task t) {
        //download file 
    }

    public void addTask(Task t) {
        tasks.add(t);
    }

    public void startRunning() {
        running = true;
        this.start();
    }

    public void stopRunning() {
        running = false;
        this.interrupt();
    }
}
```

The above code worked, but I found that even the `tasks` were empty and there are no new `task` added, the loop will keep running.

So I though if I can make the `LoaderThread` suspend when there are no tasks, and notify it when new task come out.

So I tried this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        if (tasks.size() > 0) {
            Task t = tasks.get(0);
            log.info(t);
            if (t != null && t.status == Status.waiting) {
                tasks.remove(0);
                t.status = Status.running;
                downLoad(t);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I tried to call the `wait()` if the `tasks` is empty.

But I do not know how to wake up it?

Also, is there anything I should know to improve the application?

BWT, is it possible that more than one `LoaderThread` instance will be created? If so , how to avoid it?

---

It seems that I can use other implementation, but I wonder if my case is refactor-able?

Since I want to learn some thing I have missed. :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are the standard usage of [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), so I would recommend you to use [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and not reinvent the wheel.

Base on code you provided, your servlet should look like this:

```
public class RwdServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private ExecutorService loader;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        loader = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();//or use some other executor, google about difference between them
    }
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Task t=createTask(req); //assume that task implements Runnable or Callable
        loader.submit(t); // submit a task to executor after this line your task will start execution in another thread
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        loader.shutdown();//this will destroy executor service but before that it will wait until all already submitted tasks will be executed

    }
}
```

See [link with example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html)

Comment: Can the `ExecutorService` wait and wake up automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by wake up automatically? When you initialize it and before you submit tasks `ExecutorService` in "standby mode". After you submit tasks it starts calculating it asynchronously.

Comment: How about all the tasks are finished, does the `ExecutorService` will be "standby" again, and after some time, does it will start if new task was added to the tasks?

Comment: Yes, it works as you described. Basically it will accept and process tasks until you execute `shutdown()` on it.

Comment: Hi, I have googled the ExecutorService,but I am not sure how to use it in my case. For example, where can I keep the `tasks list`? Could you spare some time to show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Your use case calls for an ExecutorService and you have started reimplementing it from scratch. Better stop now and use the finished, bug-free, flexible, and powerful product from the standard library.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not exactly sure your meaning. Do you recommend me to use the `ExecutorService` or not?

Comment: @hguser: I'm pretty sure he means that you're trying to build something that exists already, so you should stop wasting your time and use the better library. Unless you've got amazing skills, your result won't be better than what already exists. :)